How to Call HTTP GET API with Json Request body in WSO2 EI6.6.0
I want to integrate an API in WSO2 EI6.6.0 where the downstream API only accepts HTTP method GET with JSON Request body but as per WSO2 EI, it ignores the JSON request being set using the payload factory which is why the downstream gives an error. below is my code
<sequence name="moz-simo-billpay-general-process-request-seq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
            {
              "Document": {
                "ServiceReq": {
                  "Hdr": {
                    "MsgFctn": "$2",
                    "PrtcolVrsn": "$3",
                    "MsgUUID": ""
                  },
                  "ReqData": $1
                }
              }
            }
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:incomingPayload"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:operationCode"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:protocol"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property
        expression="fn:concat($ctx:mozSimoBillpayUrl, '/BillPay/V2.0.1.0/Billers')"
        name="uri.var.mozSimoBillPayUrl" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="GET"/>
    <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property expression="concat('Bearer ',$ctx:bearerToken)"
        name="Authorization" scope="transport" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http uri-template="{uri.var.mozSimoBillPayUrl}">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>120000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
<log level="full"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($)" name="response" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    
</sequence>

How can we achieve this kind of scenario in wso2 EI?

you cannot. That's the definition of GET Method. Additionally, I do not think that particular api accept JSON body with get method. So, read the document and pass appropriate data.

The API gives a successful response on GET with JSON body but gives failure while sending POST or removing the body sent to GET.
Can we use any alternatives using any Java libraries in wso2?

I do not know anything about this library. What this API would do with your data? What kind of error do you get with POST request?

it gives an "invalid user" error while using POST. I have asked from the API vendor and they are saying this is as per the specs to have GET with the request payload

This is simply an HTTP spec violation. GET requests do not support sending payloads, so you simply can't do this with WSO2 OOB components. As a workaround, probably you can write a custom class mediator, but even the underline libraries WSO2 uses like the Apache HTTP client don't allow this. So you will have to find a library that allows you to send GET requests with payloads and implement the mediator using that.

As a work-around I have created a proxy on NodeJS level and exposed as API and consumed that API from WSO2 with POST method and it worked.
